# docker RUN mkdir does not work when folder exist in prev image

Tags: linux, image, docker, centos

**the only difference between them is that the "dev" folder exists in centos image,
check the comment in this piece of code(while executing docker build)，appreciate it if anyone can explain why?**

```
FROM centos:latest 

LABEL maintainer="xxxx"

RUN dnf clean packages
RUN dnf -y install sudo openssh-server openssh-clients curl vim lsof unzip zip

**below works well!**

# RUN mkdir -p oop/script
# RUN cd oop/script
# ADD text.txt /oop/script

**/bin/sh: line 0: cd: dev/script: No such file or directory**

RUN mkdir -p dev/script
RUN cd dev/script
ADD text.txt /dev/script

EXPOSE 22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things going on here.

The root of your problem is that `/dev` is a special directory, and is re-created for each `RUN` command. So while `RUN mkdir -p dev/script` successfully creates a `/dev/script` directory, that directory is gone once the `RUN` command is complete.

Additionally, a command like this...

```
RUN cd /some/directory
```

...is a complete no-op. This is exactly the same thing as running `sh -c "cd /some/directory"` on your local system; while the `cd` is successful, the `cd` only affects the process running the `cd` command, and has no effect on the parent process or subsequent commands.

If you really need to place something into `/dev`, you can copy it into a different location in your Dockerfile (e.g., `COPY test.txt /docker/test.txt`), and then at runtime via your `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` copy it into an appropriate location in `/dev`.

Comment: thank u somuch, that's exactly what i'm looking for